# Converting Images to Base64 in GoLang

Tags: postgresql, go, base64

I am trying to convert images using Base64 encoding and save them to the database. Here is my procedure:

1. HTML page shows a button to browse for the image
2. Image is being processed by following code:

```
func HandleUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, formFileName string) (string, string, string, error) {
    // Maximum upload of 10 MB files
    r.ParseMultipartForm(1 << 2)

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile(formFileName)
    if err != nil {
        // If there is an error that means form is empty. Return nil for err in order
        // to validate result as required.
        return "", "", "", nil
    }

    defer file.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Uploaded File: %+v\n", handler.Filename)
    fmt.Printf("File Size: %+v\n", handler.Size)
    fmt.Printf("MIME Header: %+v\n", handler.Header)

    tempFile, err := ioutil.TempFile(TmpDirectory, "upload-*.png")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return "", "", "", err
    }

    defer tempFile.Close()

    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return "", "", "", err
    }

    tempFile.Write(fileBytes)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Successfully Uploaded File\n")

    // create a new buffer base on file size
    fInfo, _ := tempFile.Stat()
    var size int64 = fInfo.Size()
    buf := make([]byte, size)

    // read file content into buffer
    fReader := bufio.NewReader(tempFile)
    fReader.Read(buf)

    contentType := http.DetectContentType(fileBytes)

    switch contentType {
    case "image/png":
        fmt.Println("Image type is already PNG.")
    case "image/jpeg":
        fmt.Println("Image type is JPG, converting it to PNG.")
        img, err := jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(fileBytes))
        if err != nil {
            return "", "", "", errors.Wrap(err, "unable to decode jpeg")
        }

        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        if err := png.Encode(buf, img); err != nil {
            return "", "", "", errors.Wrap(err, "unable to encode png")
        }
    }
    //convert the buffer bytes to base64 string - use buf.Bytes() for new image
    imgBase64Str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)

    filePath := filepath.Join(TmpDirectory, tempFile.Name())
    return handler.Filename, filePath, imgBase64Str, nil}
```

3. Returned `ImageBase64Str` is written to the Database, although, I think there is a limit PostgreSQL database can accept at the input. My `ImageBase64Str` is **71000 CHARACTERS LONG!** Why is that? It looks like this:

> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...

I am assuming that this is NOT expected output.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: _I am assuming that this is NOT expected output._ Why? A 1 MiB image will encode to about 1.4 million base64 characters (2^20 * 4/3 = 1,398,102 bytes). A 17,000 character base64 string represents about 17 KiB of data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `buf := make([]byte, size)` allocates a slice of zero bytes.  The statement `imgBase64Str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)` encodes those zero bytes to base64 giving the [result you observe](https://play.golang.org/p/drl9zJhAwK_u).

A base64 encoding of data is larger than the original data by a factor of 4 / 3.  Large images will produce large encodings.

The temporary file is not needed by the function. Work with the bytes slurped up from the form file.

Here's a simplified and repaired version of the code:

```
func HandleUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, formFileName string) (string, string, error) {
    // Maximum upload of 10 MB files r.ParseMultipartForm(1 << 2)

    file, hdr, err := r.FormFile(formFileName)
    if err != nil {
        // If there is an error that means form is empty. Return nil for err in order
        // to validate result as required.
        return "", "", nil
    }

    defer file.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return "", "", err
    }

    contentType := http.DetectContentType(data)

    switch contentType {
    case "image/png":
        fmt.Println("Image type is already PNG.")
    case "image/jpeg":
        img, err := jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
        if err != nil {
            return "", "", fmt.Errorf("unable to decode jpeg: %w", err)
        }

        var buf bytes.Buffer
        if err := png.Encode(&buf, img); err != nil {
            return "", "", fmt.Errorf("unable to encode png: %w", err)
        }
        data = buf.Bytes()
    default:
        return "", "", fmt.Errorf("unsupported content typo: %s", contentType)
    }
    imgBase64Str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
    return hdr.Filename, imgBase64Str, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! However, for some reason I cannot view the image in HTML. Not sure why.